# why php always display after login sucessful?

Tags: php, html, jquery

here's my login.php file, i want to make this $loginSucess only give variable to home.html instead showing the login php (which is turned to be blank page after sucessfully login)

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $otp_code = intval($_POST['otp_code']);
    $passwordMismatch = false;
    $loginSuccess = false;

    // Database configuration
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbName = '-';
    $username = '-';
    $dbPassword = '-';

    // Create a database connection
    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    // Check if the connection was successful
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM account_identity WHERE email=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($stmt_result->num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc();
            if($data['password'] === $password && $data['otp_code'] === $otp_code) {
                 $loginSuccess = true;
            } else {
                $passwordMismatch = true;
            }
        } else {
            $passwordMismatch = true;
        }
    }
?>
```

and here's my home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Arcane City Roleplay</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2 class="logo">ARCANE CITY</h2>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Statistics</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Donate</a>
            <a href="#">Status</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <button class="btnLogin-popup" onclick="toggleLogin()">Login</button>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="icon-close" onclick="toggleSections()">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
        </span>
        <div class="form-box login" id="loginForm">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon
                    name="mail"></ion-icon></span>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon
                    name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="remember">
                    <label><input type="checkbox">
                    Remember me?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="otp_code" name="otp_code" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" required>
                    <label>OTP</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Login" name="login" class="btn">Login</button>
                <div class="login-register">
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#" class="register-link">Register
                    </a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="form-box welcome" id="welcome">
            <h2>Welcome Back</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var loginSuccess = <?php echo ($loginSuccess ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>;

            if (loginSuccess) {
                $('#welcome').show();
                $('#loginForm').hide();
            } else {
                $('#welcome').hide();
                $('#loginForm').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
    
    <div class="opening" id="openingSection">
        <h1>ARCANE CITY</h1>
        <h2>GTA 5 ROLEPLAY</h2>
        <button class="btnConnect" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.wikipedia.org';">CONNECT TO SERVER</button>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

how to fix this issues? just to let variable run and give variable back to the html instead showing php file

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text. PHP provides `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` so that you can store passwords in a secure format.

Comment: If you intend to maintain session state once the user has successfully logged in then **all** pages that the user goes to after login must be php (or able to execute php as per comment below) and each must initialise the session before writing any content. Logging in and redirecting to `.html` page will end the session (unless as per comment)

Comment: how do you pass the `$loginSuccess` variable from `login.php` to `home.html`?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the desired behavior of passing the `$loginSuccess` variable back to the `home.html` file instead of displaying the `login.php` file, you can make use of session variables.

1. In your `login.php` file, start a session by adding the following code before any output is sent to the browser:

```php
session_start();
```

2. Set the value of `$loginSuccess` as a session variable using the `$_SESSION` superglobal. Replace the line `$loginSuccess = true;` with:

```php
$_SESSION['loginSuccess'] = true;
```

3. Redirect the user back to the `home.html` file after successful login. Add the following code after setting the session variable:

```php
header("Location: home.html");
exit();
```

4. In the `home.html` file, remove the PHP code that checks the value of `loginSuccess` as we will now retrieve it from the session variable.
5. Inside the `<script>` tag in `home.html`, update the code to retrieve the `loginSuccess` value from the session variable and show/hide the appropriate sections based on the value. Replace the existing JavaScript code with the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loginSuccess = <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['loginSuccess']) && $_SESSION['loginSuccess']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
    
    if (loginSuccess) {
        $('#welcome').show();
        $('#loginForm').hide();
    } else {
        $('#welcome').hide();
        $('#loginForm').show();
    }
});
```

With these updates, when the login is successful, the `login.php` file will set the `loginSuccess` session variable and redirect the user back to `home.html`. Then, in `home.html`, the JavaScript code will retrieve the value of `loginSuccess` from the session variable and show/hide the appropriate sections accordingly.

Comment: Unless the server configuration is specifically set up, `home.html` won't run the PHP code, so it still won't work as the OP hopes. At the very least `home.html` needs to be renamed to `home.php`

Comment: i change it into php but now it always treat it loginSuccess, before i put my form

Comment: but i want to this variable work in the script
$('#welcome').show();
$('#loginForm').hide();
instead head back to home.html